# Append raster zonal statistics to layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I want to append zonal statistics to a polygon layer. I am trying the zonal statistics tool from the processing toolbox and it is working ok, but it is exporting the data to a new layer.

I don't want it to go to a new layer, I want it to be appended to the existing layer as this layer has relates with other layers of the project that I want to keep.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on one topic.

Answer (score 5):

If you create a model you have access to "Zonal statistics (in place)" which does what you want.

I dont know why this tool cant be find in the Processing toolbox?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this same issue today. The appending behaviour used to be the default one, but has been changed in recent versions for some reason. I have just verified and you can access the previous functionality with QGIS 3.10.