# Which QGIS versions has Zonal statistics (in place) tool

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

I want to append zonal statistics results to input shapefile. I can't use ArcGIS for this.

As suggested in this link I downloaded QGIS 3.10.14.
[Append raster zonal statistics to layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423790/append-raster-zonal-statistics-to-layer-in-qgis)

But Zonal statistics (in place) is not there in processing toolbox or model designer.

Do you know which version has this option?

Comment: (It is possible to get the same result with some manual work: Add a unique id field to your shapefile (if your havent got one), Zonal statistics, the output zones will have the id. Go to layer properties - Joins of your shapefile layer. Join the zonal stats output. Open the attribute table of your shapefile, calculate a new field as `"Zonal Statistics__sum"` or whatever the joined attribute column is named. Drop the join)

Comment: That is good idea. Thank you for sharing. Currently I save output as shp and replace old one with the output. But since I have more than 10 raster for zonal statistics, I am looking for straight forward option.

Comment: @BERA thank you for extending help. That will be great!